# Result of nnetar is strangely flat

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm new to R but have some experience with ARIMA models. Now I wanted to learn a bit about neural networks for forecasting.

I tried to repeat the procedure from [Rob's post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/nnetar-prediction-intervals/). It worked great for the data set he used. It also worked great for imaginary datasets I created.

But then I tried to use real-life data (revenue data for 7 years monthly) and the resulting forecasts are strangely flat. My code:

```
read.csv("Revenue.csv",header=TRUE)
x <-read.csv("Revenue.csv",header=TRUE)
y<-ts(x,freq=12,start=c(2011,1))

(fit<-nnetar(y))
fcast <- forecast(fit, PI=TRUE, h=20, bootstrap=TRUE)
autoplot(fcast)
```

The result is an almost straight line (attached as [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoQJD.png)). That strikes me as odd, because the trend has been positive so far: there was a revenue growth of more than 100% every year. Still the result of nnetar is that the revenue will stabilise. How is that possible?

As a comparison I used Auto.arima for the same data set ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqwRs.png)). It shows a clear upward trend.

Comment: Without your data it's really hard to help you. .

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, even if its hard to help without the data sample.

It appears than `nnetar` is not capturing very well the trend in your data.

Probably you could try to use a trend as external regressors ( `xreg` argument)

For example for a deterministic trend.

```
Trend=seq(from=start, to=end, by=1)

(fit <- nnetar(y, xreg=Trend))

(f <- forecast(fit,h=h, xreg=seq(from=end, to=end+h, by=1))
```

An alternative would be to use more lag or seasonal lags (`p` and `P` argument in your `nnetar` model)